# R contexts, environments, and call stacks with `.Call`

Tags: c, r

Are there versions of `parent.frame` or `sys.calls` or other general context functions that can be called directly from C code invoked by `.Call`?  Looking around the `Rinternals.h`, etc, I can't seem to find anything of the sort.  The best I can come up with is something like:

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
   .Call(my_fun_C, substitute(x), parent.frame(), sys.calls())
}
```

but ideally I'd prefer to avoid the R calls to `substitute`, `parent.frame`, etc. and do those directly from C.  Why?  Each of those function calls adds 300ns to the evaluation of `my_fun`, and while that isn't exactly going to kill me, I'd like to know if there is a way to avoid it or if I'm stuck with the above.

There is this tantalizing tidbit of code from `main/context.c` in the function `do_sys`:

```
RCNTXT *cptr;

cptr = R_GlobalContext;
t = cptr->sysparent;
```

but `RCNTXT` is defined in `includes/Defn.h`, and `Defn.h` looks to be an internal non-exported header.

Comment: Looks like Eddi explores something similar in **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686892/passing-unevaluated-expressions-to-c-c)**.