# Call match.call() from C++ code

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm having trouble calling `match.call()` from a C++ function. In the example below, the `match_call()` C++ function fails at simply forwarding its arguments to `match.call()`. What am I missing?

```
match_call <-
  Rcpp::cppFunction(
    '
      SEXP match_call(SEXP definition, SEXP call) {
        Function m("match.call", R_BaseEnv);
        return m(definition, call);
      }
    ')

match.call(function(a = 1, b = 2){}, quote(fun(b = 4, 3)))
## fun(a = 3, b = 4)
match_call(function(a = 1, b = 2){}, quote(fun(b = 4, 3)))
## error: could not find function "fun"
```

As suggested by @nicola, adding a `quote()` helps:

```
        return m(definition, Rf_lang2(R_QuoteSymbol, call));
```

This works, but doesn't explain the mechanisms.

Comment: Seems like that a call to `eval` is made on the arguments when you are calling R functions from C++. For instance, `match_call(function(a = 1, b = 2){}, quote(quote(fun(b = 4, 3))))` works, since the (implicit) `eval` call just cancels the first `quote`.

Comment: You can wrap the Rcpp function with an R function: `match_callR<-function(definition,call) match_call(definition,substitute(call))` to obtain the desired output.

Comment: @nicola: Thanks. I suspected this, but what's the reason for this behavior? You mentioned an "implicit eval()".

Comment: Can't be sure, but I think that in the C++ construct `f(a,b)` where `f` is an R function and `a` and `b` are the arguments, `a` and `b` are implicitly `eval`uated in order to make the call to the function. Hope that someone more competent (Dirk Eddelbuettel, the author of `Rcpp`, is very active on SO) might jump in and give a correct answer.

Comment: `Rcpp::Function` is one of several ways to get to it; it may enforce an early `eval()`.  Maybe try `Rcpp::Language` -- page 9 of the 'Rcpp Introduction' had that as an example for over half a decade.

Comment: Returning something like `return(Rf_lang3(Rf_install("match.call"), definition, call));` from `match_call` shows how it differs from the equivalent `quote( match.call(function(a = 1, b = 2){}, quote(fun(b = 4, 3))) )` on that the second argument is evaluated. I guess [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686892/passing-unevaluated-expressions-to-c-c) is a similar discussion.

Comment: Excellent catch @alexis_laz.